# What is the battery technology with the highest energy density?

Tags: batteries, energy

What is the battery that has the most volumetric energy density

I'm not talking about which battery on the market but which battery from ALL the battery technologies existing or theorized right now. I think it's lithium-air but I'm not sure... Also, could this battery be used on the market?

I did an internet research but some sites are contradicting each other...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_battery_types

Comment: "ALL technologies existing or theorized" and you want to know if it can be used on the market..? I have no idea what technology it is but I'm pretty sure the theoretical highest density battery is not market viable.

Comment: Also define your terms. I'm pretty sure sodium-x beats lithium-x per unit volume, but lithium-x wins per unit mass. Continuing that idea, the  clear winner is hydrogen-x. Probably hydrogen-air as long as you're in an atmospheric environment. So, yes it can be used, it's called a fuel cell.

Comment: Vanadium Boride air wins hands down with a theoretical volumetric energy density *higher* than petrol, clocking in at around 27kwh/L vs around 9.7kwh/L respectively. **However** Vanadium Boride *does not* win when scored on kwh/kg, it is a very dense material, that's what gives it a high volumetric energy density, but it's gravimetric energy density is kinda ordinary.

Answer (score 6):

That's simple - Radioisotope Thermal Generator (RTG). Power density is a bit low, but the long lifetime produces a spectacular energy density.

For instance, the Cassini RTG puts out an average of about 250 watts for 10.75 years in a 55 kg package with a volume of about 0.155m<sup>3</sup>, for a volumetric energy density of about 546 GJ/m<sup>3</sup>

And that's just for its rated lifetime. It will actually put out appreciable power for centuries, so the actual energy density is several times greater.